# how to configuring secondary IP subnet that is directly routed to WMware ESXI main IP

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, static-routes, ip-forwarding

I have a ESXI 5.1 which comes with a /29 Block IP (EX. 70.60.50.0/29) and the ESXi management address is frist usable addres 70.60.50.2, also i have a secondary /27 IP block (10.20.30.0/27) which is static routed to the primary (first usable) IP address of /29 (statically routed to 70.60.50.2) , I need to run VM and give them the IP from secondary IP block but i do not know how to do IP forwading in ESXI ! (i already did in KVM virtualization but there is no option like that in ESXI) anyone could help with this ? Thanks

Comment: VMware is not really intended to be a router in this fashion. Is this a hosted ESXi server? Do you have an option to install a small firewall/router appliance?

Comment: Yes this is a hosted ESXI , if the only option is an router appliance , i will, but i do not have any idea how to do .

Comment: I never used KVM and I don't have a reference of how you did the IP forwarding you are saying, but usually what is done in an ESXi environment when you need to connect to multiple network on the same NIC is to have vLAN Tagging or IEEE 802.1Q, it works in layer 2 and logically separates networks, and you can add that in the vNIC of the VM you want in another vLAN, that is usually provided by your network administrator once you ask for it, since you say this is a hosted ESXi I'm guessing you shold ask the company that is hosting it if they can do that.

Answer (score 0):

ESXi is meant to only do switching, that's why you have vSwitches. So in a normal application, you'd do the routing externally and just pipe in all networks as tagged traffic to the pNICs, and then assign port groups in the vSwitches with different VLAN tagging. vmkernel adapters are then a different thing, they are the Hypervisors own network adapters inside the virtual network, and these can be assigned to corresponding port groups. What I usually do in cases where I need a router is to install for example pfSense on a VM on the host and do the required L2 plumbing to get what I want. So in your case you'd need to assign a different IP to the host, assign 70.60.50.2 to a router/fw of some sort, virtual or otherwise, and have that VM/physical box do the routing between the networks. For a really basic setup, you could actually use a Windows VM even.